# What is the proper syntax for inserting variables into a SELECT statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I believe I have a simple syntax problem in my SQL statement. If I run this code, I get an error in the database query.

```
$user = $_GET['linevar'];
echo $user;  // testing - url variable echos correctly
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `userAccounts` WHERE `name` = $user";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in db query");
```

If I replace `$user` in the `$sql` string with `'actualName'` or a known record in my table, the code works fine. Am I using the `$` variable incorrectly in the SQL string?

Comment: Your current approach on queries is subjected to SQL Injection attacks. One of the reasons for that is that you are inserting data you received from user input (`$_GET`/`$_POST`) but you are not sanitizing/ validating/ escaping it in any way. Another reason for that is that you are not using prepared statements (the old `mysql_*` functions do not support prepared statements) try learning about [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: @MihaiStancu Absolutely. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11346729/869912). The `mysql_*` functions are not only insecure, but deprecated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the value that you're getting from `$user` with quotes, since it's probably not a number:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `userAccounts` WHERE `name` = '$user'";
```

Just as a note, you should also read up on SQL injection, since this code is susceptible to it. A fix would be to pass it through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['linevar']);
```

You can also replace your `or die();` logic with something a bit more informative to get an error message when something bad happens, like:

```
or die("Error in db query" . mysql_error());
```

Comment: -1, since `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't a good fix. A good fix would be to use prepared statements and PDO/MySQLi. It's especially important for beginners to learn the proper, secure ways as early as possible.

Comment: @pythonscript - Seriously? Given the scope of the question, what's more appropriate?

Comment: In my opinion, what's more appropriate is pointing out when someone, especially in a solution, suggests using deprecated functions that are insecure. For the OP, I don't believe that beginning to learn PHP/MySQL by learning deprecated functions is a good idea. It starts bad habits that may be difficult to break.

Comment: @pythonscript - The OP's issue is with the SQL syntax, not the MySQL driver, not to mention my answer states "A fix", not "The best fix". If you want to badger him about best practices when his problem is not with the MySQL driver, do it in the comments like everybody else.

Comment: In situations like this, my custom is to a) answer the question to the best of my ability (which I did), and then b) warn about using the `mysql_*` functions and provide information about the best practices. So far, it [hasn't been a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/136534/187647).

Comment: Thank you both - I appreciate both the direct solution to my issue (my confusion with `&' quotes) and the discussion with the proper and secure ways to write better code.

Comment: @pythonscript - What's your point? My answer doesn't have SQL injection, so that meta question is irrelevant. (Not to mention that the community and OP of that question agrees more with the other answer)

Comment: I was mainly referring to the comments (not sure if I can link to those), and I even mentioned in one of the comments that I'm tempted to downvote answers I see recommending the `mysql_*` functions. That's my preference, since I'd like to see such deprecated functions cease usage.

Comment: @pythonscript - It's pretty clear that we're not going to come to any sort of agreement, which I'm more than content with accepting. You *clearly* have a **very** broad interpretation of the word "recommending". Like I said, if you want to continue your "great quest" to rid the world of the ext/mysql functions, have fun. Until that happens, enjoy your downvote, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `userAccounts` WHERE `name` = '" . $user . "'";
```

Comment: Just a note: There's a `.` missing after $user.

Answer (score 1):

You need escape the get input, then quote it.

```
// this is important to prevent sql injection.
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['linevar']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `userAccounts` WHERE `name` = '$user'";
```